# AngularJS $http data not returning correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to encapsulate data (via a JSON file) to be used across my controllers using a factory, though when I call the factory, it's executing my `$scope` before the data is returned, resulting in an empty array.

I want to be able to get the data first, then, execute my `$scope` declarations which return my data, for example:

### **Factory:**

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('StoreProducts', function ($http) {

    var storeData = [];

    var promise = $http.get('/example.json')
    .success(function (data) {
        storeData = data;
    });

    return {
        promise: promise,
        setData: function(data) {
            storeData = data;
        },
        getData: function() {
            return storeData;
        }
    };
});
```

### **Controller:**

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('StoreCtrl', function ($scope, $log, StoreProducts) {

    $scope.data = StoreProducts.getData();

    $log.log($scope.data);
});
```

### **JSON file:**

```
[
    {
        "productId": "1",
        "name": "Example 1",
        "price": "5.99"
    },
    {
        "productId": "2",
        "name": "Example 2",
        "price": "2.99"
    },
]
```

I'm thinking it's because the scope of the `getData()` function is completely off, though, I seem to think otherwise. What am I doing *utterly* wrong?

Comment: Why don't you just return promise from `getData`?

Comment: Good point @dfsq -- I did do this and it returned the promise function, not the data. do I need to chain the function? It is returning it like so: `Object {then: function, catch: function, finally: function, success: function, error: function}`, but now what? Thank you.

Comment: @Bergi, how is this a duplicate of an AJAX response call? This is directly focused on AngularJS's $http method and is derived completely away from jQuery's AJAX implementation of an HTTP request. It's not like I can write an AJAX method as defined in the answer of the supposed duplication in my AngularJS script, is it? AngularJS uses jQLite. And, as it says "**The Ajax in jQLite isn't a pure match to jQuery. It is extremely simplified due to limitations on the platform.**" The function uses **send** **complete** and **error** -- non of which I need. Both have completely different behaviours.

Comment: That canonical question is generic and not limited to jQuery's implementation of ajax calls. The problem with asynchronous callbacks is exactly the same, whether you use `jQuery.ajax`, `ng.$http`, or plain `XMLHttpRequest`. But yes, even the "Promise" solution described in an answer there is directly applicable to Angular, as it returns promises just as jQuery does.

Comment: Canonical or not, it's barely a scratch on the surface when trying to learn AngularJS methods. If I asked for a jQuery or XMLHttpRequest method, I would expect that. If I ask for an AngularJS method, I wouldn't expect someone to provide me a vanilla JS nor jQuery answer, would I? I think my questions specificity was more than enough to define what I wanted and warrants it's own question. If anything, I found a question similar to mine that got the same answer (almost), that to me, is classified as a duplicate and I would define that as legitimate. Maybe I'm in that world of SO policing *sigh*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way it's usually done is that your data function returns a promise object. From conceptual standpoint if you deal with asynchronous operation like data retrieval, `getData` cannot (and should not) simply return the value, but rather a promise.

The basic idea is this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('StoreProducts', function ($http) {
    // ... 
    return {
        // ...
        getData: function() {
            return $http.get('/example.json').then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

which you later use in controller:

```
StoreProducts.getData().then(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
});
```

Of course you can add caching layer if you don't want to query server on each `getData` call. If cached value is available, then again return promise, but this time promise resolves immediately without making a request:

```
getData: function() {
    return storeData ? $q.when(storeData) : $http.get('/example.json').then(function(response) {
        storeData = response.data;
        return storeData;
    })
}
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/bM6AK5sEQ5ZEEad4BVUu?p=preview

Comment: Thank you _ever_ so much! Perfectly executed answer. This is what I exactly was aiming for. Plus kudos to adding `$q` in there too. Is there anyway to double up that rep? Needs more rep, ASAP. Life saver.

Comment: Glad my answer helped you to learn something new!